# Active view viewable in adsense getting drastically down

Tags: adsense

On my web [odvozautom.sk](http://odvozautom.sk) I have Google Ads which had an average active view viewables around 45% but from 14/10 suddenly dropped to around 10%. Why so small? I think ads are loading slowly. Do you have any idea?

[how it looks in Google Adsense graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNApb.png)

Comment: In my personal experience, I add native ads in my Android app and then find the [active view viewable] is only 20% in some country like Brazil. It's confusing for in most country it's normally more than 90%. I'm not sure if this is related to your case, just FYR.

Answer (score 2):

Active View says about:
1 - how much of the ad was visible on the screen. At least 50% of its pixels
2 - how long was the ad visible. At least one second.

This definition is not set by Google, but by Interactive Advertising Bureau (IAB).

Active view of your website ads has dropped due to a changing of theme, or ads disposition changing, or changing of device type that your audience uses to view your content.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Adsense employs a definition different from IAB's

Here is the definition of `Active View Viewable` [as employed by Google Adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3432842?hl=en).

> All viewable ads are measurable, because you can't confirm that an ad has met the criteria for viewability unless it can be measured. For example, say the ads on your site had 100 measurable impressions. That means there were 100 impressions where Active View tags were able to measure viewability. If only 10 of those 100 impressions were measured as viewable, then the site would have 10% Active View Viewability.

This does **not** correspond to [IAB](https://www.iab.com)'s definition:

> An ad is counted as viewable if at least 50% of its area was displayed on-screen for at least one second.

Here is [more misleading information by Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3481946?hl=en). This is probably worth a class action.